# VirtualBox: Linux guest home folder inside automounted shared folder

Tags: virtualbox, arch-linux, shared-folders

I have a Windows laptop with Virtualbox. I'm virtualizing Arch Linux. I installed the Guest Additions and I can see my shared folder automounted as `/media/sf_shared`.

I created a new user with `useradd -m -d /media/sf_shared/<homedir_name> -G vboxsf <username>`. But when I try to login with it, I get a `change directory failed: Permission denied` error.

I noticed that the home directory (automatically created by the `-m` option of `useradd`) does not belong to the new user, but to root, with group `vboxsf`. I think this happens because of the way that directory is automounted on startup by VirtualBox. I don't think this should create problems, given that I added my new user to that group with `-G vboxsf`, so that it has access.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I solved my own problem. Waiting 2 days to mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

While `/media/sf_shared` belonged to `root:vboxsf`, `/media` itself belonged to `root:root`. As I'm only using it to contain the shared folder, I `chown`-ed it to `root:vboxsf` and this solved the issue. Not sure why, though.